# How to execute event functions in sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to execute multiple functions in a sequence when the user does a click on a button.

The problem I am having is that if I place one function after the other like this :

```
nextTooltipButton.onclick = function () {


          if (self._introItems.length - 1 != self._currentStep) {
              _nextStep.call(self);
          }

          $("#contenedorPage").scrollLeft(0);
          $("#contenedorPage").trigger("scroll");
      };
```

They execute either at the same time or the second one does not execute.

I come from c# where you can add various controllers (functions) to an event and they will be executed in the order in which you added them to the event.

Is there a way of doing something similar in Javascript?

Comment: If you need event handlers to be executed in a specific order, you're using them incorrectly. Bind a single event handler that does everything, or rethink your design some other way.

Comment: $("#contenedorPage").scrollLeft(0).trigger("scroll");

Comment: As you're using jQuery, you could or chain the calls, or use the callback (when available).

Comment: You could use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead of the onclick property, which will probably be cleaner and closer to what you are used to.

Comment: What is your desired outcome? I'm not sure what you're trying to say is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using jQuery, you could or chain the calls, or use the callback (when available).

**Chaining:**

```
$("#contenedorPage").scrollLeft(0).trigger("scroll");
```

Furthermore, why not write everything using jQuery?

```
$("#nextTooltipButton").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this)._introItems.length - 1 != $(this)._currentStep)
        _nextStep.call($(this));

    $("#contenedorPage").scrollLeft(0).trigger("scroll");
};
```